# Uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, reinstall

Main OS: Windows 10,
New OS: Ubuntu 16.04,
Firmware in laptop: UEFI,
Platform: 64 bit

I had created a partion in Windows 10 for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and successfully installed it. But the installation was not proper so I want to uninstall Ubuntu and re-install it on the same partition. Read it in a article that uninstalling can be done easily by deleting the partion I had created from Windows 10.

But the point is if I would be able to install Ubuntu back into same partition again. Would the grub menu let me boot into Windows 10 again to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation This seems to be the most comprehensive related answer

Comment: I wouldn't delete the partition only to have it created again. I'd just re-install and select that partition as where you want Ubuntu installed. Myself, I always use 'something else' & select partitions myself, which allows you to select format/no-format (via a check-box), and I'd possibly allow checkbox to be selected allowing reformat there. (reformatting increases chance of nothing from the past usually meaning few issues, but more to restore from backups [which won't apply for you])